# Returning two views in controller class function

Tags: laravel, function, view, return

I am trying to return two views in Laravel controller class, but I do not know how it should be done.
I want to add an additional 'payment' view in the show function
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaRbd.png)

Comment: what you mean with two views? one at the bottom of the other or what??

Comment: I think you can use modal

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rendering two views inside of the controller you should use blades `@include` tag. E.g.

```html
<!-- Some Code -->
@include('components.payment', ['somedata' => $data])
<!-- Some More Code -->
```

See the docs for more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#including-sub-views